# Render a Select as Radio Inputs using Crispy Forms

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to render a select input as a group of radio buttons in django crispy_forms. Rendering them using `InlineRadios` is not an option, as I need them to be rendered in a "normal" vertical orientation.

So far, I have tried using:

```
Field('field_name', template='bootstrap/layout/radioselect.html')
```

While this does an okay job of showing the select `<options>`, it renders them in bold font and is completely missing the `<label>` for the form group.

Am I missing something simple? Is the best way to handle this to write my own custom "layout"? If so, how can I ensure that the `<label>` is also included with the radio inputs?

Answer (score -1):

You could extend `Field` widget as `InlineRadios` does and then write down your own `radioselect` template:

```
class VerticalRadioButtons(Field):
    template = "%s/layout/radioselect.html"

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, **kwargs):
        return super(InlineRadios, self).render(
            form, form_style, context, template_pack=template_pack,
            extra_context={'inline_class': 'inline'}
        )
```

You can start from the default radioselect template and change whatever you want. Or maybe you only need to touch the CSS files to avoid the bold efect.